# Is it a bad idea to use an array with a single element instead of just a variable?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

Are there performance disadvantages when I use a single-element array over a simple variable?

I have a base class from which many other classes are derived. This base class provides a `Value` property of type object.

Now I have to also support multi-value versions of most classes. Thus I was thinking about changing  `protected object value` to `protected object[] value` and using the array even if only a single value is required.

I know the length of the array in the constructor, so in case of single-value instances, the length of the array is 1.

Since there ususally exist a lot of instances during runtime (up to several thousand, depending on number of users) I'm very concerned with performance.

So my question is: Will this change from simple variable to array cause a noticeable change in performance, or is it generally bad design?

I thought about creating a wrapper class that enables multiple values, but the classes are heavily connected via references and events, so this would be clumsy to use and maintain.

**Edit** To clarify:

The purpose of the base class is mainly to provide an interface. Other classes use the `Value` property, which is why it is defined in the base class. The variable itself was only defined in the base class so I don't have to define it in every deriving class (type is always object).

The multi-value extension is not required because there are deriving classes that need more than one value, but because there will be a context-sensitive environment (don't know how to phrase it better) and classes need to remember a value for every context.

For example, think of it as an iternationalization technique (not in my case, just as example).

A class represents a word and depending on the language, the `Value` is the word in the respective language.

By putting all the multi-value logic in the base class, deriving classes can continue to work like they always did (using the `Value` property) and the base class figures out which value to use.

Hope this makes things a bit clearer.

Comment: I suggest, you don't think about that until you really have a performance problem. See also: Premature Optimization

Comment: I didn't see anything that makes me suspect complexity reduction beyond what deriving from Object will do for you. What is the purpose/task of this base class?

Comment: The base class provides a lot of functionaltiy i didn't describe here because I thought it irrelevant to the question. It declares and provides a default implementation for several events, declares several abstract methods, etc. I would have to describe the whole system to explain in detail, which I think is not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: the amount of overhead would certainly not be noticeable.  If it reduces the code's complexity, then it is a good idea.

Comment: The question is: is it good design, so this only begs the question: how does a base like this reduce complexity? From the information given, I'd say it probably _increases_ complexity for now

Comment: I agree that this implementation seems like it might be more complex to read.  It certainly wouldn't be very intuitive to me.  I guess it would be important to know whether the original poster is working on a solo or group project.  If a group/open-source project, I may argue against doing it this way.  If solo...well it seems like he's put so much thought into it that it won't seem complex to him.

Comment: Software complexity is _not_ as subjective as it is believed to be. [Dijkstra](http://ce.sharif.edu/~ghodsi/archive/d-papers/CACM/The%20End%20of%20Computing%20Science.pdf), Wikipedia ([accidental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_complexity) vs. [essential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_complexity))

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to imply that code complexity is whatever this guy thinks it is.  All I meant was if it's a solo project, and he perfectly understands one way of doing it and not so much another, then the former way should be chosen.

Comment: There are many operations that require a class that derives from "base class", so I only require that type. I won't create 10 methods that do the same thing, only with a different parameter type. Thus the base class and the `Value` property, which is one of the few properties required for a lot of operations. I would "hide" the array from deriving classes, so they would continue to work with the `Value` property, not knowing (or caring) whether they are single- or multi-value. In case of multi-value, only 1 value at a time (namely the "current") must be of interest for deriving classes.

Comment: @enzi: I assume you have heard of generics: `bool MyOperation<T>(T myparam) { }` - you can add constraints, like e.g. ` where T: class, ISupportMyOperation`, you can have `params T[]`, `ref T`, `out T` parameters...

Comment: @sehe: Thank you, I'm familiar with generics. I only meant to describe how I use the base class in my previous comment. Anyway, generics cannot replace a base class if that is your suggestion. I can use `List<BaseClass>` and pass a list of any classes that derive from `BaseClass`, but I can't do the same with generics without using a base class.

Comment: @enzi: Fair enough, but you didn't state the need two comments up. Also, if you worry about flexibility lost (and potentially future performance pain as a result), I still think that a runtime switch on the actual element type is far superior: it will have about the same performance (if not equal) and no tax on the class hierarchy (both in design tax and runtime cost)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be more performance hungry to change an array into a single variable and vice versa. I wouldn't mind having an array with the possibility to expand with one value!

Answer (score 1):

It is adding overhead, but I doubt that it will be noticeable under "normal" circumstances (e.g. not a in a tight loop).

Answer (score 1):

Without having seen your code, I get a feeling that one could question the design. You have a base class that can hold one or more "values", of arbitrary type? Generally, I would use a base class to contain properties and/or functionality that are common to the deriving types, but if I notice that the base class tries to "fit all possible needs" of the deriving classes it's probably time to refactor. In this case, your base class to me seems a bit too general.

That being said, it's possible that your specific situation justifies the design. (And I don't think you would notice any performance degradation.)

Answer (score 1):

Why is there a need for (a) a global base class (b) one that also provides variable storage?

This seems like ... unnecessary restriveness (or ... bad design if your prefer). I don't know any context, of course, but I suggest more along these lines:

```
public interface IValueProvider<out T> /* : IComparable<T>, IEquatable... etc */
{
    T Value { get; /*protected?*/ set; }
}
```

If you insist, you can have implementation helpers, like so:

```
public class ValueProviderClass<T> : IValueProvider<T> 
     where T : class, new()
{
     ValueProviderClass() { Value = new T(); }
}
```

Of course also structs can implement the interface, yielding even more room for performance optimization if the need arises in the future (however, value types will not be able to transparently derive from a 'base' valuetype because the CLR doesn't allow that)

Note the use of Covariance to get compatibility with IValueProvider, e.g.

Hope this idea helps you spark some more lean-and-mean thinking

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the class generic and specify the type of Value when the class is instantiated?